# Redirect not working for a drupal multisite installtion

Tags: drupal, .htaccess, drupal-6

I have a drupal mustisite installation and Im using drupal domain access module. I have sites like www.abc.com and www.cde.com pointing to the same codebase.

However, while redirect for abc.com to www.abc.com works, redirect for cde.com  to www.cde.com doesnt work? Any idea on how to fix it?

Im redirecting using htaccess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The redirect rule I had used previously was not correct. I finally used the one below and it worked like a charm

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.cde\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.cde.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Apologies for inconvenience!